# Tapping between activity and user icon on official iOS app crashes app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

This bug is easily reproducible.

1. Go to official Stack Exchange iOS app.
2. Click between activity (graph icon) and user icon.
3. ???
4. <s>Profit</s> App crash

It happens all the time for me on an iPad mini running iOS 9.3. I have not tried it on a different OS version or device.

Comment: Is there something between the "activity" (graph icon? Achievement?) and "user" (profile?) icon? If possible, could you add the screenshot where you click?

Comment: Seems like it has been fixed.